# Upper bounding incomplete gamma function

Tags: integration

For $0<\theta, \lambda<1$ and  $c>1$, we wish to upper bound the following gamma function:
$$\int_{\theta}^{1} 
t\exp \left(-c\left(\lambda t+\frac{1}{t}\right) \right)dt$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't say that you need an optimal bound, so I just give a bound. I assume that $0<\lambda<1$ and $0<\theta<1$.

Using the arithmetic-geometric inequality,
$$
\lambda t+1/t\geq 2\sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
Hence
$$
\exp(-c(\lambda t+1/t))\leq \exp(-2c\sqrt{\lambda}),
$$
and the integral is bounded by
$$
\exp(-2c\sqrt{\lambda})(1-\theta^2)/2.
$$

**Slightly better:**

Instead of using AM-GM inequality, since $\lambda<1$ the minimum of $\lambda t+1/t$ is attained at $t=1$, so
$$
\lambda t+1/t\geq \lambda+1.
$$
The rest is as before, and your integral is bounded by
$$
\exp(-c(\lambda+1))(1-\theta^2)/2.
$$

Comment: thanks for your response! Could it be further tighten.

Comment: In fact, it seems that it is pretty tight as it is. It could of course be better, in particular for $c\approx 1$. But for $c>5$, say, it is pretty good. I think you have to tell more explicitly what you need.